# Changing the height of ComboBoxItem when dropdown is opened

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, dropdown

I am trying to change the size of the image inside the `ItemContainer` when I open the `ComboBox`.

When the `ComboBox` is closed, the `Image` control should fit the height and width of the parent, and when it's opened, the height and width of the image should be higher, so I can see the schema that's being displayed in the `ComboBoxItem`.

This seems to work, however, the `TextBlock` is disappeared when I open the dropdown.
I'm not sure why that happens.

```xml
<ComboBox Name="cbxCreatesOn"
          Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="1"
          Width="140"
          Height="32"
          ItemsSource="{Binding CreationTypes}"
          SelectedIndex="{Binding CreationType, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ComboBox.IsEnabled>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BooleanAndConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="cbxCreateSection" Path="SelectedIndex" Converter="{StaticResource IndexToBoolConverter}"/>
            <Binding ElementName="selectedSectionsText" Path="Text" Converter="{ui:ConvertStringIsNotNullOrEmptyToBoolean}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </ComboBox.IsEnabled>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemContainerTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="1"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ItemContainerTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="70"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izSP7.jpg)

Comment: Why do you set the `Height` of the `ComboBoxItem`. Can you provide a picture that visualizes your issue?

Comment: @mm8 I added an image with the results. I set the Height so that it doesn't display the image at full size. If I don't do that, it will be very large.

Comment: Then you should set the size of the `Image`.

Comment: And why are you using an `ItemContainerTemplate` instead of a `DataTemplate`?

Comment: I don't know how to use DataTemplate on items made up of multiple controls.

Comment: I see no image on the picture you have posted. Are you sure that the bindings work?

Comment: Yes, it's just a white image for testing. Bindings work.

Comment: Where does "Test" come from? Could you please provide a minimal reproducible sample?

Comment: The text "Test" and image name (which is just a white image in the project's Resources) are passed from the ViewModel.

Comment: On the ViewModel, I have an ObservableCollection of objects and the class used contains only two properties, Text and ImagePath, which you can see in the XAML.